# How do you update records using pickle module?

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.7

So I'm trying to update some records that I've saved in a binary file using pickle.dump..
I'm a beginner and I'm not sure why it isn't working. Can anyone help out?
Here's the code:

```
def modify():
    f=open('employee.dat','ab+')

    e=int(input('Enter Employee Number:'))
    while True:
        try:
            rec=pickle.load(f)
            for a in rec:
                if a[0]==e:
                    print('Presently:')
                    print('Emp_no.         ' , a[0])
                    print('Employee Name:  ' , a[1])
                    print('Salary:         ' , a[2])

                    a[0]=int(input('Enter NEW Employee Number:'))
                    a[1]=input('Enter NEW employee name      :')
                    a[2]=int(input('Enter NEW salary         :'))

                    pickle.dump(rec,f)
                    break

            else:
                print('Employee Number not found!')
        except EOFError:
            break
```

The program accepts the first input of employee number but there's no output after that.

Comment: Remove the try and see if there is an error while loading file

Answer (score 0):

1. When opening a file object in append mode, the file object's position by default is the end of the file. So, when you try to loop through the file, pickle won't be able to read the file and will throw an error like this:

   EOFError: Ran out of input

   - To fix this, add `f.seek(0)` after you open the file object.

Plus:
    "Errors should never pass silently.", as stated by "Tim Peters" in "The Zen 
 of Python". I'd suggest you just remove the try-except block from your code, because it's considered bad practice to unknowingly silence errors.

2. When you're looping through the `rec` list, you're updating the `a` variable, which is just a local variable of the for loop. Updating the `a` variable won't actually change the original list. To achieve your desired result, you must get the items by indexing the original list.

Answer (score 0):

See the builtin [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) module in python.